# Finding the amount of an ER20 token in ethereum transaction web3 from the hash of an ethereum swap?

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py, etherscan

I'm trying to get the amount of a token sent in a crypto transaction and it's proving to be more difficult than I thought.

I'm using the web3 module as follows, but I can't get the function to work correctly.

I believe I need to decode the input section of the transaction as follows:

```
        uniswap_factory = '0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f'  
        uniswap_factory_abi = json.loads('[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_feeToSetter","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token0","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token1","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"pair","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"PairCreated","type":"event"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"allPairs","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"allPairsLength","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"}],"name":"createPair","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"pair","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"feeTo","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"feeToSetter","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"getPair","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_feeTo","type":"address"}],"name":"setFeeTo","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_feeToSetter","type":"address"}],"name":"setFeeToSetter","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]')
        contract = web3.eth.contract(address=uniswap_factory, abi=uniswap_factory_abi)

        #pancakeswap router abi
        ethRouterAddress = '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D'
        ethabi = '[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_WETH","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"WETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountADesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBDesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addLiquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenDesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addLiquidityETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"factory","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveOut","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getAmountIn","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveOut","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getAmountOut","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"}],"name":"getAmountsIn","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"}],"name":"getAmountsOut","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveB","type":"uint256"}],"name":"quote","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHWithPermit","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityWithPermit","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapETHForExactTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactETHForTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMax","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapTokensForExactETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMax","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapTokensForExactTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]'
        contractbuy = web3.eth.contract(address=ethRouterAddress, abi=ethabi)


        print(tx)
        print(tx['input'])
        amount = contractbuy.decode_function_input(transactions_mentioned[0]['input'])
```

does anybody have any experience getting this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I think your `print(tx)` will show the Dict object containing `logsBloom, data, blockNumber, transactionHash, logIndex`,  etc...

You have to look inside of "data".

For example, I tested with a simple token swap using 0.000000000001234567 BNB.

`print(tx)` of my swap transaction returns to me this:

```
'data': 
'0x
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012d687 <- input amount
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003ac54'
```

We can see the input amount (12d687). We just need to convert it to decimals. (result: 1234567)

Obs: In this case I used BNB, so we have to divide "1234567" by (10**18) to get the Ether value.

If you use another token, just divide it by (10**Decimals of token)

[Click here to see convert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwhyz.png)